# How to know whether actual current value is null in Firebase Realtime DB Transactions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, es6-promise

A firebase transaction handler should be able to handle null values, as well as it can be called multiple times. What happens if it is called on a location with a null value. (If there is no existing data) Is there a way to know it from the proceeding promise. How about following code?

```
let isNull = false;
db.ref('/entry').transaction( currentValue => {
  if(!currentValue) {
    isNull = true;
    // Do the updates
  } else {
    // Do the update
  }
  return currentValue;
}).then(() => { 
  console.log("IsNull", isNull);
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in the `then` method.  Please read the API docs for what the fulfilled promise gives you.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

Comment: It is something depending on whether the value is null or not. For an example I am assigning a task for a `person`. I am writing it to `/tasks/{uid}/` using a transaction. Tasks can be assigned only if the person do not have a task already. Then I wanna know whether  that person got the task assigned? Because otherwise I need to assign it to another person.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on state outside the transaction like that.  Use the data in the promise to determine what to do next.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson Yeah. I will try to rely on that. One more thing, In what kind of cases the `{committed}` variable be `false`?  Is it like a network failures.

Comment: Any time the transaction didn't write any data.  Maybe because you canceled it.

Answer (score 0):

**This example is to check whether a particular user Id is under a node**

Use something on the lines of:

```
//Add this before OnCreate while declaring all variables
FirebaseUser firebaseUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

yourDatabaseSource.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final String thisFirebaseUser = firebaseUserId.getUid();
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(thisFirebaseUser)) {

                   //check your condition

                } else {

                   //do something
                }
            }
```

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: Thanks for the message, Actually this is not what I am expecting to do. It's more about how to handle concurrent updates. This one doesn't guarantee the value is not on the child node until we update. Needs to use a transaction for that.